# Emgu CV Camera Calibration

Tags: c#, emgucv, camera-calibration

I am trying to calibrate my camera using Emgu CV 3.0.0 with Visual Studio 2012.

I want to find out the information like extrinsic, intrinsic and distortion parameters for the camera through 20 different angles of chessboard images so that I can use the camera to find other points on other images image and convert them into a world coordinates.

I can only find some examples from older version of EmguCV. May I have some codes or some links where can I find learn or perform the task that I need?